# Find the scalars such that $v_4$ can be written as $v_4=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find the scalars such that $v_4$  can be written as  $v_4=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$, where
$$v_1=(1, 1, 1),\quad   v_2=(1, 2, 3),\quad   v_3=(1,1,2),\quad v_4=(2,1, 3).$$

Comment: I didn't because i dont know how find the scalars

Comment: Just by looking at the given vectors you can notice that both $v_1$ and $v_2+v_4$ have the same number on each coordinate. So you get $3v_1=v_2+v_4$. Can you express $v_4$ from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. The equation $v_4=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$ implies that component-wise the following equations hold:
$$c_1+c_2+c_3=2,\quad  c_1+2c_2+c_3=1,\quad  c_1+3c_2+2c_3=3.$$
Can you take it from here?

Note that by subtracting the first and the second equations from the third one, we find immediately that $c_1=0$.

So it remains to solve:
$$c_2+c_3=2,\quad  2c_2+c_3=1.$$

Comment: Then could you explain more pls

Comment: @user395584 Enjoy this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcYbFN49uGc

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1=(1,0,0),\space e_2=(0,1,0),\space e_3=(0,0,1)$

By some observations we can find that:-
$$e_3=v_3-v_1$$
$$e_2=(v_2-v_1)-2e_3=v_1+v_2-2v_3$$
$$e_1=v_1-e_2-e_3=v_1+v_3-v_2$$

We know $v_3=2e_1+e_2+3e_3$. Substitute above expressions and simplify to calculate the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You have to argue componentwise:

By looking at the first component you obtain the equation
$$c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot 1+c_3\cdot 1=2.$$
From the second
$$c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot 2+c_3\cdot 1=1$$
and from the third
$$c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot 3+c_3\cdot 2=3$$
All of these must be satisfied at the same time, so they build a linear system. Solve this by the techniques you know.